# Selecting from one table and modifying it before importing

Tags: sql, select, sql-update, ssms

I have since modified this process and hopefully simplified. In the past, I had two tables, tablename and result. Tablename had a column (56th of 90) named cnty which was char(3). The second table, result, had a field which essentially was 000 + cnty. This field is titled area. I was trying to insert the cnty values from tablename, add the three zeros at the beginning and place them in the result table under the column, area.

Now I have both columns in result. Area is blank for now. Cnty contains the values that were in tablename (79954 of them).

Sample data

```
 area     employment      busdesc      cnty
               410      gas station    003
```

Desired Result

```
  area     employment      busdesc      cnty
 000003        410       gas station     003
```

Comment: Edit your question and add both tables structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
update dbo.result 
            set area = concat('000',cnty);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had to reimport my source data. Something scrambled it up. I will try this query once I have finished the task.

Comment: @TimWilcox Ok..No rush

Comment: I have since changed the process. I now have cnty and area in the same table. Area is blank and cnty is 003 (for example). Would your query still work exactly as written?

Comment: @TimWilcox Is it like you added new column area in result table and now you want to store the values of area based on value of cnty?

Comment: @TimWilcox Try this query and tell me whether it works (it must though): update dbo.result r set r.area = concat('000',cnty);

Comment: Ok, will do so. I have since edited the question. It may make more sense now.

Comment: @TimWilcox I think creating new question is a better idea, coz now all other answers will be mislead to the next viewers or others have to delete their answers.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'r'.

Comment: @TimWilcox Forgot 'as' keyword: update result as r set r.area = concat('000',cnty);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154387/discussion-between-tim-wilcox-and-harshil).

Answer (score 1):

```
update res
set res.area = '000' + tbl.cnty
from Result res inner join [originalTable] tbl 
 on res.id=tbl.id --Don't know how to join both tables, let us know
```

EDIT: In regard to the last comment, let's create a new table Results2 (because I don't know all the columns in the table) This table will have all columns of tablename plus new Area column.

```
select *, '000' + cnty as AREA 
  into Results2
    from dbo.tablename;
```

You have to specify each column or in this case an asterisk `*` will do

Comment: I am quite the novice to this and have not learned how to do join tables. I am assuming that when you type "res" that it is short for "Result".

Comment: yes, res is an alias for Result, see in `Select` statement. tbl is an alias for originalTable (I don't know the name). The inner join operation matches each item from one table to identical key in the other table. In this case, I don't know which is this key (maybe name1?)

Comment: I added name1 to the sample data just to give it some context. It does not change when going from "tablename" to "result". My "result" table has 29 columns but only one of which undergoes this change.

Comment: there should be a key column (or group of columns) that univocally identifies one row from other rows. And the same goes to the other table that has cnty field, to match each row.

Comment: For the result table, There are three primary keys; state, account and unit. They are columns 1,4, and 5. Areatype and area are 2 and 3. There are 24 other foreign keys but I know how to deal with them.

As for the "tablename" table, there are no primary keys. It is created by importing a very large fixed width file.

Comment: I'm confused. Are we talking about two different tables? one that needs the update in area and another hat hast the field cnty, or is just one table and you what to create a new table call result with this modification?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154175/discussion-between-tim-wilcox-and-horaciux).

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help any further. You need to analyze your data set and find a key to match each row from one table to the other one.

Comment: Not sure how else to say it. The second table is empty and filled in items from "tablename".

Answer (score 0):

Is this the syntax you are looking for?

```
insert into dbo.result (name1, area)
    select name1, '000' + cnty
    from dbo.tablename;
```

Or, if the table doesn't already exist:

```
select name1, ('000' + cnty) as area
into dbo.result
from dbo.tablename;
```